# ArrayField including multiple DateTimeFields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to develop a django model, which includes `ArrayField` of `DateTimeField` as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Predictions(models.Model):

    timestamp = ArrayField(models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True))
    ip = ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True))
    ip_status = ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True))
```

The `timestamp` will be from now until 2 minutes later, namely something like `{04/10/2022 09:30, 04/10/2022 09:31, 04/10/2022 09:32}`.

Is something like that feasible?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use SQL in your case ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi No, it is not, but I would like to use postgreSQL, because I have already some experience with it.